# Swift: TableView and a SegmentedController crash if the arrays have different count of objects

Tags: swift

I'm trying to load different arrays in a TableView based on a  Segmented Control, but if the arrays have different count of objects, the app crashes while scrolling the table with an error 'fatal error: Array index out of range.' If all 5 arrays contain equal count of objects, everything is OK :) Below is the part of the code where I set the tableview. I believe there's something wrong the way I do it ...

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    var returnValue = 0


    switch(segment.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        returnValue = MeatData.count

    case 1:
        returnValue = BreadData.count


    case 2:
        returnValue = FishData.count

    case 3:
        returnValue = BevData.count

    case 4:
        returnValue = FruitsData.count

    default: fatalError("unknown section")

    }
    return returnValue
}


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SegmentsCELL

    let photoMeat = UIImage(named: "Meat")
    let photoBread = UIImage(named: "Bread")
    let photoFish = UIImage(named: "Fish")
    let photoMilk = UIImage(named: "Bev")
    let photoFruits = UIImage(named: "Fruits")

    let meatIndex = MeatData[indexPath.row]
    let fishIndex = FishData[indexPath.row]
    let breadIndex = BreadData[indexPath.row]
    let milkIndex = BevData[indexPath.row]
    let fruitsIndex = FruitsData[indexPath.row]

    switch(segment.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:


        cell.nameCell.text = meatIndex.name
        cell.calEmptyCell.text = String(meatIndex.cal)
        cell.protEmptyCell.text = String(meatIndex.prot)
        cell.fatEmptyCell.text = String(meatIndex.fat)
        cell.carbsEmptyCell.text = String(meatIndex.val)
        cell.imageCell.image = photoMeat


        break
    case 1:
        cell.nameCell.text = breadIndex.name
        cell.calEmptyCell.text = String(breadIndex.cal)
        cell.protEmptyCell.text = String(breadIndex.prot)
        cell.fatEmptyCell.text = String(breadIndex.fat)
        cell.carbsEmptyCell.text = String(breadIndex.val)
        cell.imageCell.image = photoBread

        break
    case 2:
        cell.nameCell.text = fishIndex.name
        cell.calEmptyCell.text = String(fishIndex.cal)
        cell.protEmptyCell.text = String(fishIndex.prot)
        cell.fatEmptyCell.text = String(fishIndex.fat)
        cell.carbsEmptyCell.text = String(fishIndex.val)
        cell.imageCell.image = photoFish

        break
    case 3:
        cell.nameCell.text = milkIndex.name
        cell.calEmptyCell.text = String(milkIndex.cal)
        cell.protEmptyCell.text = String(milkIndex.prot)
        cell.fatEmptyCell.text = String(milkIndex.fat)
        cell.carbsEmptyCell.text = String(milkIndex.val)
        cell.imageCell.image = photoMilk

        break
    case 4:
        cell.nameCell.text = fruitsIndex.name
        cell.calEmptyCell.text = String(fruitsIndex.cal)
        cell.protEmptyCell.text = String(fruitsIndex.prot)
        cell.fatEmptyCell.text = String(fruitsIndex.fat)
        cell.carbsEmptyCell.text = String(fruitsIndex.val)
        cell.imageCell.image = photoFruits

        break
    default:
        break
    }

    return cell

}

@IBAction func segmentAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    table.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: What was your question again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is causing the crash:

```
let meatIndex = MeatData[indexPath.row]
let fishIndex = FishData[indexPath.row]
let breadIndex = BreadData[indexPath.row]
let milkIndex = BevData[indexPath.row]
let fruitsIndex = FruitsData[indexPath.row]
```

Move fetching of the data source item from the array to appropriate `case` sections.

#### Example

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SegmentsCELL
            
    switch(segment.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        let meatIndex = MeatData[indexPath.row]
        let photoMeat = UIImage(named: "Meat")

        cell.nameCell.text = meatIndex.name
        cell.calEmptyCell.text = String(meatIndex.cal)
        cell.protEmptyCell.text = String(meatIndex.prot)
        cell.fatEmptyCell.text = String(meatIndex.fat)
        cell.carbsEmptyCell.text = String(meatIndex.val)
        cell.imageCell.image = photoMeat
        
        
        break
    case 1:
        
        let breadIndex = BreadData[indexPath.row]
        let photoBread = UIImage(named: "Bread")

        cell.nameCell.text = breadIndex.name
        cell.calEmptyCell.text = String(breadIndex.cal)
        cell.protEmptyCell.text = String(breadIndex.prot)
        cell.fatEmptyCell.text = String(breadIndex.fat)
        cell.carbsEmptyCell.text = String(breadIndex.val)
        cell.imageCell.image = photoBread
        
        break
    case 2:
        
        let fishIndex = FishData[indexPath.row]
        let photoFish = UIImage(named: "Fish")

        cell.nameCell.text = fishIndex.name
        cell.calEmptyCell.text = String(fishIndex.cal)
        cell.protEmptyCell.text = String(fishIndex.prot)
        cell.fatEmptyCell.text = String(fishIndex.fat)
        cell.carbsEmptyCell.text = String(fishIndex.val)
        cell.imageCell.image = photoFish
        
        break
    case 3:
        
        let milkIndex = BevData[indexPath.row]
        let photoMilk = UIImage(named: "Bev")

        cell.nameCell.text = milkIndex.name
        cell.calEmptyCell.text = String(milkIndex.cal)
        cell.protEmptyCell.text = String(milkIndex.prot)
        cell.fatEmptyCell.text = String(milkIndex.fat)
        cell.carbsEmptyCell.text = String(milkIndex.val)
        cell.imageCell.image = photoMilk
        
        break
    case 4:
        
        let fruitsIndex = FruitsData[indexPath.row]
        let photoFruits = UIImage(named: "Fruits")

        cell.nameCell.text = fruitsIndex.name
        cell.calEmptyCell.text = String(fruitsIndex.cal)
        cell.protEmptyCell.text = String(fruitsIndex.prot)
        cell.fatEmptyCell.text = String(fruitsIndex.fat)
        cell.carbsEmptyCell.text = String(fruitsIndex.val)
        cell.imageCell.image = photoFruits
        
        break
    default:
        break
    }
    
    return cell
    
}
```